# Querying a database via desktop application / security

Tags: c++, mysql, database, qt

I'm going to write a desktop application using the Qt framework that should then be released to the public. But I'm worried about the safety of this approach.

I usually code in PHP therefore I'm aware of SQL Injections and anything database related to make any query secure but I came across a problem I've never faced before: desktop application send queries **from the client** to a server therefore, I've heard, is not as secure as server to server (PHP).

What are the main security risks, how Qt prevents them or how can I prevent them by specific coding techniques?

*I'm sorry I cannot be any more specific but I'm not really experienced in the desktop application field.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Qt does nothing for you to protect your data. You should focus in securing your RDBMS first.
Of course you should code your Qt client application carefully to prevent unintended behavior by checking and sanitizing all inputs, etc. but if you're not going to distribute it, this shouldn't be your most immediate concern.

If you plan to use PostgreSQL as the backend for your application, you can take some measures to mitigate the risks that comes with exposing any service to the internets. 
The most basic:

- Setup a firewall with proper rules. Allow inbound connections from trusted sources only.
- Accept SSL connections only, even with a self-signed certificate.
- Enforce strong passwords. Use client certificates if more appropriated.
- Set your `pg_hba.conf` file to only accept connections from known/trusted addresses.

Debian/Ubuntu have excellent PostgreSQL packages. Right after installing you can easily setup PG to allow SSL connections without going on the hassle of  generating certificates manually.

Relevant PostgreSQL docs:

- [Secure TCP/IP Connections with SSL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/runtime-config-connection.html)
- [Client Authentication](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/client-authentication.html)
- [Client Connection Defaults](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/runtime-config-client.html)

I can provide you a very basic example Qt application (unfinished) that was designed to work with PostgreSQL if you want. Just let me know.

**Edit:** uploaded the example app to GitHub: [exampleapp](https://github.com/dschulz/exampleapp.git). Tried to tidy up but there's still a mess with a lot of strings that were originally written in spanish. At any rate, you can still find a bit of useful code if you're starting with Qt. 
Oh, and I'm using Qt5 and had to compile my own PostgreSQL driver for Qt (not a big deal if you're on Linux). I mention this because the app might or might not compile with Qt4. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Regarding

> desktop application send queries from a computer to a server

I don't know the exact situation you're thinking of but keep in mind that stored procedures can be used in this situation to mitigate risk of sql injection. If the desktop application only has rights to call a series of stored procedures on the db server and nothing else then you've reduced the risk considerably. If the desktop client cannot be trusted at all then the alternative is  to not let the client desktop application access the db directly. You could write a layer to reside on the server which  does all the db access for the clients and the client interact with that rather than a db.

Comment: I'm more concerned about the queries and the connection be publicly available because they must travel from the client to the server.

Comment: So you're worried about packet sniffers? I guess then only an encrypted db connection will do or if you choose to create server layer that the client talks to then it would have to be an ssl encrypted connection.

Comment: Is that the only security risks in this context?

Comment: Possibly the direction you may want to take is writing a web service that runs over ssl. Without further detail I can only guess.

Comment: I'd really like to avoid server side scripting as much as I can.

Comment: If you're worried about passwords being sniffed out then encrypting the connection is the only choice. If you're allowing other people to also write client software to connect to your db then something along the lines of a web service may be right. If your just worried about sql injection then dont allow clients software to send sql to the db , force them to call stored procedures instead.